How to access pcie virtual memory from kernel
I am currently using a xilinx MPSoC in a PCIe EP application. I used already successfully the the EP in a baremetal application but now I would like to port my application to linux.
So now th issue arrised when I tried to access this pcie virtual memory mapped to a Outbound/Egress BAR.
I get a  "Kernel panic - not syncing: Asynchronous SError Interrupt".
So i dunno if my assumption is correct or not, but looks like the mmu is not working or mapping properly.
Any ideas where I could start looking for?
SError Interrupt on CPU3, code 0x00000000bf000002 -- SError
CPU: 3 PID: 750 Comm: devmem Tainted: G           O      
Hardware name: xlnx,zynq (DT)
pstate: 60000000 (nZCv daif -PAN -UAO -TCO -DIT -SSBS BTYPE=--)
pc : 000000000040bf70
lr : 00000000004b6830
sp : 0000ffffeac85c10
x29: 0000ffffeac85ce0 x28: 00000000005bfa68 x27: 0000000000400310
x26: 00000000005c9000 x25: 0000000000000018 x24: 0000000000000002
x23: 0000000000000000 x22: 0000ffffeac85ec0 x21: 0000ffffeac85e98
x20: 0000000000000021 x19: 0000ffffeac85e98 x18: 0000000000000001
x17: 0000000000000000 x16: 0000000000000000 x15: 0000000000000000
x14: 000000000360ed96 x13: 0000000000000018 x12: 00000000005c8f6c
x11: 0000ffffeac85cf0 x10: 0000000000000010 x9 : 0000000000557a40
x8 : 000000000000000f x7 : 0000000000558340 x6 : 0000000000002000
x5 : 0000ffffeac86e1c x4 : 0000000000000003 x3 : 0000000000000000
x2 : 0000000000000010 x1 : 00000000005c1000 x0 : 0000000000000000
Kernel panic - not syncing: Asynchronous SError Interrupt
CPU: 3 PID: 750 Comm: devmem Tainted: G           O     
Hardware name: xlnx,zynqmp (DT)
Call trace:  
 dump_backtrace.part.0+0xc0/0xd0
 show_stack+0x18/0x30
 dump_stack_lvl+0x6c/0x88
 dump_stack+0x18/0x34
 panic+0x164/0x31c
 add_taint+0x0/0xb0
 arm64_serror_panic+0x6c/0x7c
 do_serror+0x28/0x70
 __el0_error_handler_common+0x40/0xa4
 el0t_64_error_handler+0x10/0x20
 el0t_64_error+0x190/0x194
SMP: stopping secondary CPUs
Kernel Offset: disabled
CPU features: 0x00000,01000100,0000420b
Memory Limit: none
---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Asynchronous SError Interrupt ]---


There should be another kernel log message from pr_crit("SError Interrupt on CPU%d, code 0x%016lx -- %s\n", smp_processor_id(), esr, esr_get_class_string(esr));, and possibly a register dump.

@IanAbbott Many thanks for your reply. Yes,there is I just posted the all log message.
